# Chrome console: difference between 'let' and 'var'?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, var, let

I've attached an animated gif to illustrate this weird behavior. Essentially, my question is does Chrome console treat `var` and `let` differently when used in the same scope? You'll notice that after declaring / assigning a variable, if you try to type that variable's name into the console, Chrome will autocomplete it for you, showing a dropdown list containing what your typing. When using `let`s, this is not the case. Is this a bug, feature, or is there something I'm missing about `var` and `let` in JavaScript?

Note: I'm well aware that `let` lives & dies within the immediate scope.

[image]

Comment: Without being a member of the chrome development team, I'd say  a) they only look for the global scope variables in their autocompletion, or b) didn't care implement it for `let` yet, or c) they forgot to implement it

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you make that gif image?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov yeeeees. That's the most interesting part of the question!!!

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov... hahaha. It's done with an age-old trusty program from the good folks over at Cockos called [LICEcap](http://cockos.com/licecap/). Enjoy!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `var` in the console, it executes in the global scope and adds the variable to the `window` object.

When you use `let` in the console, it executes in the global scope, which doesn't add the variable to the `window` object.

When you start typing, autocomplete checks the parent object for properties to complete along with other language constructs, such as `function`, `for`, and `while`.

When there is no content in the console, the parent object is `window`, which won't have the property you're looking for because `let` doesn't add the property to `window`.

As soon as you have a new object for autocomplete to complete, behavior returns to what you'd expect.

```
> let foo = {bar: 'baz'};
> foo.b //autocompletes bar
```

---

Now, with all of that said, there's no reason that autocomplete *has* to behave that way. In many regards the lack of autocomplete for variables defined in global scope via `let` could be considered a "bug" worth "fixing". In my opinion it is moderately surprising behavior.

Answer (score 1):

[`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) defines a variable on the global scope, while [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) defines it only in the local scope. Most likely, the autocomplete is only looking on the global scope for targets.

Comment: It's all logical. But now end of 2017 and chrome don't autocomplete `let` variables yet( Firefox did it. Do you know any information about how we can get autocomplete for `let` variables in chrome?