# Why do I get ReferenceError when defining variable with `let` in Chrome console when paused with debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I have `o` variable in my script. In console when paused in debugger I'm declaring `z` variable with `let`. Then I try to access it but get `ReferenceError`. It works fine with `var`. Why?

[image]

Comment: have you tried "var" instead of "let"? I tried it and it works for me

Comment: @MariusB, yes, sure, it works fine with `var`

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39397220/3194701) answer will help you

Comment: @MariusB, thanks, I'll take a look